# how to print the position of a symbol in matrix, which forms right triangle

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

We need to input a number of columns and rows, also we need to input a symbol.
For example:

```
5 8 *
asdferyh
jfgty*jh
gdhffldh
gfjkklll
fjfjj*f*
```

Output must be: 5 6

Comment: please make this question clearer.  what is that gobbledy gook of letters?

Comment: Please share some code, because it is not entirely clear what are you asking. Also, welcome to StackOverflow!